# Assigning zip filename in Java and convert it as ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I am currently trying to create zipfile using ZipOutputStream and return it back as ByteArrayOutputStream.

However currently wondering how can I assign a filename for the zip itself.

Right now it will always be generated with the name 'application.zip' which I don't want.

I tried assigning it using FileOutputStream but after decoding it it still use the default naming so no luck.

Here's the code:

```
    private static ByteArrayOutputStream convertZipToByte(
        final String fname, final String content) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("usethisinstead.zip");
        baos.writeTo(fos);
        final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fname);

        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(content.getBytes());
        zos.closeEntry();

        return baos;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // throwing error ex here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is just writing an empty file, move `baos.writeTo(fos);` to the end and close all the open streams with try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should always close streams at correct point, try-with-resources deals with this automatically.

Split your zip from the file writing makes the logic simpler, and re-use NIO calls, something like this:

```
private static ByteArrayOutputStream
convertZipToByte(final String fname, final String content, final Path zip)
    throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fname);

        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(content.getBytes());
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
    try(OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(zip)) {
        baos.writeTo(fos);
    }

    return baos;
}
```

In order to call the above make a file system `Path` such as with:

```
convertZipToByte("content.txt","Hello World", Path.of("my.zip"));
```

Comment: The issue persist. When I encode the ByteArray and decode it later on, the zip will be renamed into 'application.zip'. I need to make sure that the zip filename stays intact.

Comment: As application.zip is not mentioned in the code in your question, then I suggest you edit the question with details of the code you are actually running.